# vim ctags, jump to the definition of a class method

Tags: vim, ctags, class-method, source-insight

When I use ctags in vim, I run into this problem:

InputDevice *device = mdev;
device->process(...);

when i wanna see the definition of process of class InputDevice, ctags can't give a solution and it shows so many tags.
While in source insight, it can just jump to the correct definition place because it finds tag "device->process" not only tag "process".

I found cscope can't do it eigher.

Is there a method which can find the right tag definition?

Comment: Not possible with ctags / cscope. Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190955/how-to-find-struct-member-uses-with-cscope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two way

1. ctags

   you can jump by "Ctrl + ]"

   but you should use "--*lang*-kinds" with "m" to create tag file. more info with "ctags --list-kinds".
2. [eclim](http://eclim.org/)

   In default [mapping](http://eclim.org/vim/mappings.html), you can jump by "Enter" key

Comment: Thank you! I forgot this post. Does "--lang-kinds" with "m" means    "m class, struct, and union members"(result by ctags --list-kinds)? I'll try your method, thanks very much.