# Structure member search in cscope

Tags: cscope

How to search structure members/structure combinations in cscope. For example I want to search for `my_s.x`

```
typedef struct _s{

    int x;
} S;

int fun(){
    S my_s1;

    my_s1.x=10;
}

int main(){

    int x = 1;

    S my_s;

    my_s.x = 5;

    fun();

    return my_s.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this as well.
Basically there is no way to do this.

I found this while searching for solution:
[How to find struct member uses with cscope and ignore local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190955/how-to-find-struct-member-uses-with-cscope)